# Django Session - set two related data into one session variable

Tags: django, session

I have these following two data which I want to save into session, so that I can call all of them in last-preview page:

```
1) product title, 2) product size
```

I am wondering how to save this into session. My problems are: Session keys are unique so I cannot name the session name with some name. another issue is that these 2 data are coming dynamically. So I cannot use the product title as session key.

I want that both data is saved in one session variable.

Comment: So you want to store multiple product title/size pairs in a single session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session variables are simply stored as the json-serialization of the actual value. This means that you can use lists, tuples and dictionaries, and any other json-serializable values.

One solution is to store your products as a list of `(name, size)` tuples. Then you can do:

```
if request.session['products']:
    request.session['products'].append(('name', size))
else:
    request.session['products'] = [('name', size)]
```